# How to access the index before i in Python?

Tags: python

struggling a bit understanding how to access indices in Python loops. How would you write this code in Python?

```
int x = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] + s[i - 1] == x) {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
```

So far, I have tried the enumerate method, but I don't think it's working as intended.

```
x = 5
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if (i, c + (i - 1), c == x):
        print("Success")
```

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't really find a solution to this exact way of handling indices in Python loops. Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: x = 5
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i]+s[i-1] == x:
        print('Success')

Comment: What is `s` in your question ?

Comment: Is it a bug or a feature that the pair of first and last elements of `s` are tested together?

Comment: What is the error you get? What do you expect instead?

Comment: s is a list, or an array in the Java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering `s` to be a sequence, assuming is to be a sequence with numbers and considering the first Java-style code in the first part

```
s = [0,1,2,3,4,5,..]
x = 5

for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i] +s[i-1] == x:
        print("Success")
```

Comment: Note that the Java code starts at `0` and not `1`, so it checks if the first and last elements sum up to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c + s[i - 1] == x:
```

`c` here will be an element from the list referring to `s[i]` and i will be index variable. In order to access the element at `i-1`, you need to use `s[i - 1]`. But when `i` is 0, you will be comparing `s[0]` with `s[-1]` (last element of `s`) which might not be what you want and you should take care of that.

Comment: Try this values: `s=[0,0,5,5,6,5]` and `x=5`, it should print one time, but it will print two times, that is because of `s[i -1]` in the first iteration.

Comment: I mentioned that in the answer that it might not be what you want to do during the first iteration as i will be 0. The Java code in the question was starting the loop from 0 and I didn't want to deviate from that.

Answer (score 0):

the enumerate() method splits the lop target in a tuple containing the index, and the element of the target.
Unlike c style languages, when you use a for loop in python without the enumerate, i represents the element. This means that you do not have to insert the index in the list when calling it.
Your code in python would be like this.

`s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # the list named s.
x = 5
for i in s:
    if i + i-1 == x:
        print("success")`

Since we're only working with integers, you could do like this as well

`x = 5
for i in range(10):
    if i + i-1 == x:
        print("success")`

Comment: I want to access the number in the i-th index, not the i-th index itself. In your example, aren't we adding 1 + 0, then 2 + 1, and so on?